# ignore to the n° whitespace with ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have a data file with a lot of columns of doubles but I want to read only two of them with a while loop

```
    double x, y;
    ifstream in;
    double foo;
    while( in >> foo ) {
       in >> foo;
       in >> foo;
       ...
       in >> x;
       in >> y;
       ... something with x and y
    }
```

Two questions

1) There is a way to do the same thing without a fake double foo?

2) there is a way to do that without repeat in >> foo (or a for loop) like stream to the n° whitespace with a one-line code? There is a built-in function to skip to the n° whitespace?

Comment: Is the input file arranged such that the number of bytes to the start of the first input variable is always the same?  If not, after reading the second input variable, are the number of bytes to the start of the next input variable a fixed value?

Comment: I dont think that should matter here. The OP is not reading in binary mode and whitespace characters would be skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would suggest instead is to read an entire row in a string and use a stringstream to manipulate it or just use something like find_last_of functions from the string class itself to pick out the last two columns and then convert it back to a double.